# Can I connect a Magic Trackpad to a USB bluetooth dongle instead of my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, bluetooth, magic-trackpad

I know the Magic Trackpad is pretty hard to use with two different MacBook and there is that unpair/pair manipulation to do.

But I would like to know if I could not do a pretty workaround.

I have one of those USB-C screen where only one cable connects power, screen, and the screen's USB hub. My girlfriend and I are both using that screen. So my question is, can I let one USB dongle on that screen and connect the trackpad to that dongle, so that it is always working on the computer being used ?

I do not want to mess up with my bluetooth, like I want to keep my bluetooth working when unplugged. But I don't mind that my Macbook uses the dongle when connected (at least if I can still pair multiple devices).

Thank you for reading me !